# config @wordpress/scripts with webpack and postCSS features

Tags: wordpress, npm, webpack, package.json, postcss

I using wordpress as CMS and I want to config @wordpress/scripts with webpack and adding PostCSS and it's plugins like: postcss-loader, postcss-import, postcss-simple-vars,postcss-nested, postcss-mixins, autoprefixer

as my files looks (package.json and webpack.config.js) that every thing installed and config is not having any error on vscode terminal some of the postcss features working and some other not.
for example postcss-loader, postcss-import,postcss-simple-vars,postcss-nested works fine but  postcss-mixins, autoprefixer not working.

For example if I create nav like this breakpoint mixin is not working and also the autoprifixer not works:

```css
@define-mixin max-width-1100 {
    @media (max-width: 1100px) {
      @content;
    }
}
ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        justify-content: flex-start;
        align-items: center;
        list-style: none;

        @mixin max-width-1100 {
            flex-direction: column;
        }
    }
```

```html
<ul class="index-ul">
    <li>Ali1</li>
    <li>Ali2</li>
    <li>Ali3</li>
    <li>Ali4</li>
</ul>
```

now I added my package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "portfoliotheme",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "wp-scripts build",
    "start": "wp-scripts start",
    "dev": "wp-scripts start",
    "devFast": "wp-scripts start",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@wordpress/scripts": "^26.15.0",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.16",
    "css-loader": "^6.8.1",
    "postcss-import": "^15.1.0",
    "postcss-loader": "^7.3.3",
    "postcss-mixins": "^9.0.4",
    "postcss-nested": "^6.0.1",
    "postcss-simple-vars": "^7.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "normalize.css": "^8.0.1"
  }
}
```

and this is my webpack.config.js:

```
//Import the orginal config from the @wordpress/scripts package
const defaultConfig = require("@wordpress/scripts/config/webpack.config.js");

//Import the helper to find and generate the entry points in the src directory
const { getWebpackEntryPoints } = require("@wordpress/scripts/utils/config");

const path = require('path');


//Add a new enty point by extending the webpack config
module.exports = {
    ...defaultConfig,
    mode: 'development',
    entry: {
        ...getWebpackEntryPoints,
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/scripts', 'main.js'),
    },
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'assets/dist'),
        filename: 'main.bundle.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    'style-loader',
                    'css-loader',
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            postcssOptions: {
                                plugins: [
                                    require('postcss-import'),
                                    require('postcss-simple-vars'),
                                    require('postcss-nested'),
                                    require('postcss-mixins'),
                                    require('autoprefixer'),
                                ],
                            },
                        },
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
}
```

Any useful help would be appreciated.